# React Native font awesome regular icon could not be found within the project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, font-awesome

I am using font awesome icons in react native like so:

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome"
import { faArrowLeft } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faArrowLeft"
import { faPlus } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faPlus"
...
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArrowLeft} size={50} />
...
```

I want to change the "solid" to "regular" in the imports. I have done `npm i --save @fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons`. I get `@fontawesome/free-regular-svg-icons/faArrowLeft could not be found within the project or in these directories: node_modules`.

Answer (score 0):

`import { faArrowLeft,faPlus } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons"`

It has been awhile im using FontAwesome.I think this is the correct syntax.